# 2 sliders with difference version of jQuery on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, version, sliders

I have problem with 2 sliders on one page, because first use jQuery 1.9.1 and second 1.5.1, I found how to fix this problem, but it doesn't want to work.

I do it right that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
       console.log($().jquery); // This prints v1.5.1
       console.log($j().jquery); // This prints v1.9.1
      });
   </script>

<script src="js/jquery.slides.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $j(function() {
      $j('#slides').slidesjs({
        width: 950,
        height: 364,
        navigation: {
          effect: "fade",
          active: false
        },
        pagination: {
          active: false,
          effect: "fade"
        },
        effect: {
          fade: {
            speed: 1500
          }
        },
        play: {
            effect: "fade",
            auto: true,
            pauseOnHover: true
        }

      });
    });
  </script>
<link type="text/css" href="jquery/css/blitzer/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>


<div id="main">
<script  type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',minDate: +0, maxDate: '+8M +10D',monthNames: ['Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec','Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień'],dayNamesMin: [ 'Nd','Po', 'Wt', 'Śr', 'Cz', 'Pt', 'So']});
        });
        $(function() {
            $( "#dateToo" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',minDate: +1, maxDate: '+8M +10D',monthNames: ['Styczeń','Luty','Marzec','Kwiecień','Maj','Czerwiec','Lipiec','Sierpień','Wrzesień','Październik','Listopad','Grudzień'],dayNamesMin: [ 'Nd','Po', 'Wt', 'Śr', 'Cz', 'Pt', 'So']});
        });     

        $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider();
        });
</script>
```

Anyone knows why it doesn't work?
When I tried alert with version of jQuery it shows property, but when I use it in sliders, it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Use `<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>` above one of your jquery and replace the `$` with  `jQuery`

> Like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> //Now replace this jquery's $ with jQuery
```

Comment: I found newer version of 2nd slider and now both are working on 1.9.1, so I don't have to use 2 version of jQuery, but thank that you wanted to help me, maybe in future I will use it.